# Wordpress theme not updating in Other browsers

Tags: themes

I just bought a theme and installed it in my wordpress site. I've setup the theme and when I try to access from mobile and also other browsers on the same pc that I used to edit, I see the old theme. Please tell me a solution. 
This is my website : https://blackhaat.com

P.S : Not just with the purchased theme, but also other themes are not being updated.

Comment: It's just the cloudflare cache. Go to Cloudflare dashboard and find the purge cache option.

Comment: @OmarSoliman Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @OmarSoliman If this is the right answer, please include it as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the Cloudflare cache.

Go to Cloudflare dashboard and find the purge cache option then click Purge.